# Want to change opencart category plugin to show subcategories

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed the category plugin and have it displayed down the left hand side of my site. It currently shows the main parent categories but I would like to know how to change it so that it shows the submenu items instead (I only have one level below the parent categories).

The code I currently have is:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
 <div class="box-category">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li>
      <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried suggestions in other posts to use $child but I wasn't sure how to do it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is another case of trying to kill an ant by bazooka...

If You do not want to display the parent categories in Your opencart at all why on earth are You using them then? Just move the child categories so they become the parents (first level) and remove the old parents.

This is also better for users. Imagine the case (assume You are using SEO and have set all the SEO keywords for categories and products) that You have a parent category *Notebooks* and the child categories *Netbooks*, *Ultrabooks*, *Tablets*, *Laptops*, etc. Then a product underneath *Netbooks* (let's say *Asus EEE*) will have this URL: `http://yourstore.com/notebooks/netbooks/asus-eee`. But If You have hidden the parent category *Notebooks* the user will ask: "where did the /notebooks/ part come from?" and in next step he will remove the `/netbooks/asus-eee` part from URL to hit `http://yourstore.com/notebooks` to see what happens...

I think that hiding the parent categories and listing only the child ones will just confuse users... So if there is no real reason for this do as I suggested above (first paragraph).

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question, the parent categories are shown in the header at the top of the page, I wanted to use the left side panel (the category plugin I refer too in my question) to show the subcategories as it seemed pointless to just duplicate the parent categories again down the side of the page. Thanks for your answer. My issue has now been resolved.

Comment: Well, then I am sorry for misunderstanding, anyway a an advice for You for future - be more descriptive and explanational in Your question to avoid the misunderstanding :-).